# ASP.NET MVC Kendo UI chart vertical scrolling

Tags: kendo-ui

I have the following code :

```
<div overflow:auto class="chart-wrapper">
            @(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model).Name("chart")
    .Title(title => title
        .Text("Comments per day")
        .Align(ChartTextAlignment.Left)
    ).Legend(legend => legend
        .Visible(false)
    )
    .Series(series =>
    {
        series.Column(
            model => model.SE

        );
        series.Column(model => model.SL)
        .Labels(labels => labels.Background("transparent").Visible(true));
    })
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
        .Categories(model => model.Year )
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
        .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
    )
    .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
        .Max(28)
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
        .Visible(false)
    )
) 

   </div>
```

I would like to add vertical scrolling to this chart. How would I go about this?

Comment: Does your `chart-wrapper` CSS class have an explicit height? Also, what is `overflow:auto` doing on your `div` tag? That should be defined in the CSS as well.

Comment: Yes chart-wrapper have an explicit height, as for the overflow:auto i had no idea that it should be in my CSS class, in fact i'm not that good in CSS,do you have any clue ? and thinks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Kendo has scrolling and panning, which is very effective in my experience.  I would note, you must set min/max counts on the category axis to make it work. 
https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/bar-charts/pan-and-zoom